# Regarding seamless cub map textures

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3

I am not sure how seamless cubmap works. What i know is that with this feature, at the edges there is smooth color changes between two edges.

So, i am rendering a cube with 8*8 texture on each face and i am calling glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS) just before glTexImage2D() call. But i dont see any difference in the output by adding glEnable call above. I am expecting there is smooth color change a the edges of cube. I am using GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE mode for wrapping and GL_NEAREST for minification and magnification filtering.

code:

```
    GLbyte subpix[]={0, 0, 0, 127,     127,127,127, 127,  127,0,127,127,  0,127,0,127, 0, 127, 127, 127,  127,127,127, 127,   0,0,0,127,  127,127,0,127, 127, 0, 0, 127,
                            0, 127, 127, 127,  127,127,127, 127,   0,0,0,127,  127,127,0,127, 0, 0, 0, 127,    127,127,127, 127,  127,0,0,127,  0,127,0,127, 127,127,0,127,
                            0, 0, 0, 127,    127,127,127, 127,  127,0,0,127,  0,127,0,127, 0, 0, 0, 127,     127,127,127, 127,  127,0,127,127, 56, 32, 54, 127,
                            0, 127, 127, 127,  127,127,127, 127,   127,0,0,127,  0,127,0,127, 127, 0, 0, 127,    0,127,127, 127,  0,0,0,127,  127,127,0,127, 54, 100, 12,127,
                            127, 0, 0, 127,    0,127,127, 127,  0,0,0,127,  127,127,0,127, 56, 32, 54, 127,  54, 100, 12,127,  123,54, 12, 127,  32, 127, 23, 127, 21, 90, 111,127,
                        0, 127, 127, 127,  127,127,0, 127,    127,0,0,127,  0,127,0,127,  127, 0, 0, 127,    0,127,127, 127 , 54, 100, 12,127, 56, 32, 54, 127
        };  

  *target11=GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP;

        glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glGenTextures(1, &textureId);"));      


        glBindTexture(*target11, textureId);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS);

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X+i, 0, GL_RGBA16_SNORM, 7 ,7, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE,subpix);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexImage2D(types[i], 0, *format, 7 ,7, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pix31);"));
            }   

        glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
        nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);"));

         glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
         nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);"));

         glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);"));

    glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            nResult |= GL_ERROR_CHECK((GL_NO_ERROR, "glTexParameteri(*target11, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);"));
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: @Nicol really sorry for typo, corrected it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and GL_NEAREST for minification and magnification filtering.

You're using point sampling; you explicitly *asked* for seams between every texel. So there's nothing to make seamless.

Seamless cubemapping is all about doing *filtering* between faces of the cube. You're not doing filtering at all, so you're not using seamless cubemapping.

Comment: @Roshan: Changes to do what? Generally, when you turn off filtering, you have a reason to do so, right?

Comment: Sorry but i don't get you. I want to use seamless cubmap filtering in my code. How can i do that? Can you please provide a code for it.

Comment: @Roshan: Don't use GL_NEAREST but GL_LINEAR or (if you have uploaded mipmaps) GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR.

Comment: @datenwolf: you mean, min and mag filter to GL_LINEAR ? and rest of the code same in above?

Comment: @Roshan: Yes exactly that. You must enable texture filtering and GL_NEAREST effectively means "disable filtering"